# When is it recommended to start making dll's

Tags: c#, wpf, xna

I was just wondering when is it recommended to make dll's, when your project is over 1000 lines, 5000lines, more? Also should I make dll's for WPF controls that WinForm project uses?
Or maybe when the project has reached some number of classes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this question doesn't really meet the Q&A format expected here.  this is more of a discussion point, better suited for a forum.

Comment: This is very project specific - voting to close. But if you need a answer: full moon is good time to do so :)

Comment: The only real answer is "when it makes sense for you to do so". It's perfectly okay to have a single monolithic project if you're not reusing parts of the code, and you don't need to version them independently. Your component structure should be based on how things fit together, not on arbitrary measures.

Comment: The best answer is: Whenever it makes sense.  There's nothing wrong with having one giant project with all your code, if you can keep it well organized and use namespaces well.  But if you're going to be sharing it with several projects you're going to want to break it up.

Comment: When you have a group of classes that you can envisage reusing as a library. Hence the name dynamic link *library*. If there's no intent of reuse, then don't complicate matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely a matter of personal opinion, but if you're breaking up into projects due to line count or number of classes, you're doing it wrong.  you should have a project (and thus a dll) for every high level logical grouping within your solution.  you might have a data project, a domain project... etc.  if you're going to be reusing code across solutions, then yes, you'll need a dll for that, or a shared project, or something similar.